# How can I access a lua file with a tab bar?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, tabbar

I am having an error when trying to access a file with a tab bar constructed within it. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong. Corona SDK tells me my error is in the section of code where I actually create the tab bar, not the buttons. Thanks

Below is my code for the MainPage.lua scene in which the tab bar is created.

```
local tabBar = nil
function scene: create (event)
local group = scene.view
local tabButtons = 
{
    {
        width = 20, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/home.png",
        overFile = "assets/PressHome.png",
        label = "Home",
        font = tabLabelFont,
        size = tabLabelFontSize,
        onPress = function() composer.gotoScene( "Home" ); end,
    },
    {
        width = 20, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/Explore.png",
        overFile = "assets/Explore.png",
        label = "Explore",
        font = tabLabelFont,
        size = tabLabelFontSize,
        onPress = function() composer.gotoScene( "Explore" ); end,
    },
    {
        width = 20, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/Post.png",
        overFile = "assets/Post.png",
        label = "Post",
        font = tabLabelFont,
        size = tabLabelFontSize,
        onPress = function() composer.gotoScene( "Post" ); end,
    },
    {
        width = 20, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/Notification.png",
        overFile = "assets/Notification.png",
        label = "Notification",
        font = tabLabelFont,
        size = tabLabelFontSize,
        onPress = function() composer.gotoScene( "Notification" ); end,
    },
    {
        width = 20, 
        height = 32,
        defaultFile = "assets/Profile.png",
        overFile = "assets/Profile.png",
        label = "Profile",
        font = tabLabelFont,
        size = tabLabelFontSize,
        onPress = function() composer.gotoScene( "Profile" ); end,
    }
}

-- Create a tab-bar and place it at the bottom of the screen
tabBar = widget.newTabBar
{
    top = display.contentHeight - 50,
    width = display.contentWidth,
    backgroundFile = "assets/tabbar.png",
    tabSelectedLeftFile = "assets/tabBar_tabSelectedLeft.png",
    tabSelectedMiddleFile = "assets/tabBar_tabSelectedMiddle.png",
    tabSelectedRightFile = "assets/tabBar_tabSelectedRight.png",
    tabSelectedFrameWidth = 20,
    tabSelectedFrameHeight = 52,
    buttons = tabButtons
}
group: insert(tabBar)
composer.gotoScene("Home")  
end
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
return scene
```

here is the method from the log in page that is supposed to access the tab bar page.

```
local function EnterPage( event )
    composer.gotoScene("MainPage")
end
```

this is what the error is saying

```
stack traceback:
    ?: in function '?'
    ?: in function <?:703>
    (tail call): ?
    ?: in function <?:122>
    (tail call): ?
    MainPage.lua:127: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ?: in function <?:797>
    (tail call): ?
    LogIn.lua:78: in function <LogIn.lua:70>
    ?: in function <?:218>
```

line 127 of Main Page is the line that states "tabBar = widget.newTabBar"
The errors in the log in page just go to the gotoScene(MainPage) method

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I put an edit into the post

Comment: What line (or lines) are directly before that stack trace? It should indicate what the actual error is. That stack trace is unfortunately unhelpful because of the large amount of tail recursion (and possibly debug symbol stripping) involved.

Comment: File: ?
Attempt to index a nil value

Comment: so it's not very helpful

Comment: Yeah. Someone more familiar with corona is going to need to chime in here since I don't have the intuition/information necessary to make sense of that error in this context. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

"File: ? Attempt to index a nil value" is very helpful: it says that you are doing an operation of the form `a.b` like `a.b = something` or `a.b()` where `a` is nil. Given the line it happens on, this is surely because you forgot

```
widget = require 'widget'
```

near the top of your file.

If that line is already there (in `MainPage.lua`), then check that `widget` hasn't been overwritten:

```
print('widget is', widget)
tabBar = widget.newTabBar
...
```

If it is not nil then you have made an error in the information you posted (wrong line number, etc) or maybe you tried many things and info got mixed up. You could try, just to be sure,

```
widget = require 'widget'
tabBar = widget.newTabBar
```

If that works, then you know you are overwriting `widget` somewhere in your `MainPage.lua`, in code not shown. You should also try

```
test = widget.newButton
{
    left = 100, top = 200,
    label = "Default",
    onEvent = function() print('hi') end
}
```

If that works, but the newTabBar still doesn't work, try replacing your options with those of the example on corona newTabBar site.

Comment: nope that line is in the code, I just didnt include it in the section of code provided on this page

Comment: @domladj there aren't too many possibilities, I have updated.

Comment: the output is

'widget is         table: 09CF08C0'

widget is not called/used anywhere else in the program except for the two lines 'widget = require 'widget'
tabBar = widget.newTabBar'

also there are no tables or table calls anywhere in the program

Comment: @domladj did you try the last part of my answer, starting with `widget = require 'widget'`?

Comment: That has been in my code at the very start of each file, I just did not post that section of code.  Any other ideas?  Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @domladj I'm saying you should add it right at that line that I show in my answer, not rely on the one you already have. Please try and also try the new button.